# Pointers to good reference on writing AppleScriptable Cocoa project?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos, applescript

I've got an Objective-C program that I need to make AppleScriptable. I've looked through the Apple references and they're all at exactly the wrong level, either for the applescripter, or too high level, or too low level.

Can anyone point me at a good resource for getting started on this? or perhaps a sample project I can poke at?

thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's surely subjective but I think Apple's [Cocoa Scriptability](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ScriptableCocoaApplications/SApps_intro/SAppsIntro.html) is a decent document. Did you find it too high level? or too low level? Depending on that I need to change how I answer you.

To get started, Apple has a nice set of sample codes:

- [SimpleScripting](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/samplecode/SimpleScripting/Introduction/Intro.html)
- [SimpleScripting Properties](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/samplecode/SimpleScriptingProperties/Introduction/Intro.html)
- [SimpleScripting Verbs](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/samplecode/SimpleScriptingVerbs/Introduction/Intro.html)
- [SimpleScripting Objects](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/samplecode/SimpleScriptingObjects/Introduction/Intro.html)

Comment: I second this. These sample projects are where it is at. You do them in order, each builds on the last, and each has a good readme explaining what is happening. A word of warning.. I was pretty excited when i found the App "SDef editor" but it seems to be out of date and even opening an sdef file (and not saving) will mangle it irreparably - Don't go near it.

Comment: yeah, the scriptability pages were mostly too high level. They mostly talk about what scriptability is, and why you would want it, and a little about how to write scripts, etc. But not much on how to make a project scriptable... I'll take a look at those examples. those look very helpful, thanks!